# How can I redirect to my home page after a state update in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am working on my first vue project, and am having an issue with the redirect that I want to have happen. My project is a basic to-do app. In my add todo component I have the following function that fires after I submit the form.

```
  methods: {
    addTodo:function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()

      let newTodo = {
        title:this.title,
        completed: false,
        dueDate: new Date(this.date3)
      }

      console.log(newTodo)

      this.$emit('add-todo', newTodo)
    
      window.location.href = '/';
    }
  }
```

The event that is emitted then fires up the component tree until it reaches my app.vue file that fires the following method:

```
 addTodo: function (newTodo) {
        this.todos = [...this.todos, newTodo]
        this.todos = this.todos.sort((a,b) => a.dueDate - b.dueDate)
      }
```

Unfortunately the issue I am having is that my page redirects to my home page from the window.locatio.href method before my app can update state. I have also tried moving window.location.href='/' to the addTodo method in my app.vue file. However I am still facing the same problem. How can I redirect the user only once the new Todo is added to state?

Comment: Can I ask why do you need multiple routes in a todo app? Whats in your home page?

Comment: When you redirect to the homepage it will refresh page causing the application to be reloaded and the state is set back to its original state.

Comment: Would there be a way of rendering a different component after firign the add todo method that wouldn't make the page reload?

Comment: Since you're using `vue-router`, just do [`this.$router.push('/')`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-push) instead of `window.location.href='/'`.

Answer (score 0):

use **created(){}** after the last},then add **window.location.href="/"**;

Comment: Would that be in component that has my add todo form, or in my app.vue component?